# Adding a postgresql schema name in sqlalchemy url will result in a password error

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, sqlalchemy, schema

I'm generating a sqlalchemy url and passing it to another service.

For postgresql, i need to create a url with a schema.

We are creating a PSQL URL as shown below.

```
postgresql+psycopg2://{user_name}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{dbname}?options=-csearch_path%3D{schema_name}
```

This works fine on Mac, but on Ubuntu I get the authentication error below when creating a URL like the one above.

```
connection to server at {host}, port {port} failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user {user_name}
```

Just remove the schema name from the URL and it works fine.

Below are the things I've tried, all to no avail.

1. replace '%3D' to '='
2. replace '-c' to '--'

How should I set the schema name?

(I can't add metadata to the query lookup because you're just setting the URL and passing it around).

Comment: I don't get an error with that url format.  Are the auth settings (pg_hba.conf) the same on both machines?

Comment: I guess the obvious question would be, does the password work correctly on that machine without the schema specification?

Answer (score -1):

It appears that you are attempting to use the PostgreSQL URL's query parameter to define a schema name. But instead of defining the schema, the options portion of the URL is often utilized for connection options. You should adjust the schema for your PostgreSQL connection in a different way.

Try the following
first connect to you postgres database as super user or as a user who has privileges.
Then set default schema for the user using this command.

```
ALTER ROLE your_username SET search_path = your_schema_name, public;
```

Your user will default to the given schema after running the SQL statement. The SQLAlchemy URL no longer needs to contain the schema name.
Here is an illustration of what your SQLAlchemy URL should look like without the schema:

```
postgresql+psycopg2://{user_name}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{dbname}
```

Hope it works :)